# error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist

Tags: android, import, netbeans-7.4

My Android app did work well (API 15) untill I wanted to include Google ads.
Although google-play-services.jar is in my project library and it contains  com.google.android.gms.ads, the debugger comes up with an error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist when using:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
```

I tried several solutions,  but none of them worked.
I changed from Android 4.03 API15 to Google API15 but nothing changed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If anybody is getting this error with cordova when running `ant release` and it's 2015 or later, this issue might help: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/179

Answer (score 4):

There might be several years have been already gone but no good solution. So, someone like me facing the same trouble till today. I have solved it by the following method (check the attached figure)-

[Add the marked line in the gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BIL6.png)

Add the following code in the gradle.

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Better add some description.

Comment: I am in pain... nothing works here... tryed several options... BUT only useless info in the google...   please, how did you get that info? tks!

Answer (score 3):

You must import google-play-services_lib that is located in the folder `<android-sdk-directory>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` and declare it as library of your project.

You will find more informations on [Set Up Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: how to import "google-play-services_lib" ????   lots of confusing google links in the net.. and that link "Set Up Google Play Services SDK",   does not teach this...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when building an ionic cordova project after adding the plugin `admob-google-cordova` and running `ionic cordova build`. For me I went into my `project.properties` (`platforms/android/project.properties`) file and changed the line from `cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+` into `cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0`.